# Why do I get a error when I run this command? $mate public/hello.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to create the "Hello World" test page, and I run this command

```
$ mate public/hello.html
```

This is the error that I get

```
sh. exe" : mate: command not found
```

Anyone have any ideas as to why I am getting this error?

Please Note: I am running off of Windows 7 and using Notepad++ as my text editor.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're following a tutorial for someone running Mac OS X with TextMate installed.

Since you're using Notepad++, edit your files with Notepad++.